# Uncaught SyntaxError em um código ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou criando um chat, porém no console ele dá o seguinte erro:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Código: http://www.redepurple.com.br/social/Code/chatjs/chat.js

O que pode ser?

Obrigada!

Comment: Qual a linha do erro? E que ficheiro diz na consola?

Comment: Ele dá esse erro enquanto digita a mensagem na textarea dashboard:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Qual a linha do erro? na consola diz a linha em que o erro ocorreu.

Comment: Só diz isso: dashboard:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Consegues reproduzir o problema num jsFiddle?

Comment: http://oi68.tinypic.com/wvea0z.jpg

Comment: Carrega no triangulo no inicio de cada linha para expandir a linha e ver a stack.

Comment: ta em branco  :\

Comment: @TenaAndrade você vai ter que debugar seu código, provavelmente tem algum parentese abrindo e não tá fechando.

Comment: ja olhei e não acho erro nenhum

Comment: Quando der o erro no console, clique em cima dele ou do nome do arquivo que fica ao lado direito. Ele vai apontar a linha do erro. Daí você nos mostra...

Comment: Ele só mostra essa linha: (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: 41 Use '===' to compare with '0'.

Comment: Agora achei como ver a linha :)

Comment: @TenaAndrade Conseguiu corrigir o erro ? O Stack não está me notificando quando você me responde aqui...

Comment: @Gumball oie amore, ainda não, estou no JShint que ele diz os erros, mas eu não consigo, pode me dizer o que significa isso? The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype. Nessa linha: for (x in newMessagesWin) {
   newMessagesWin[x] = false;
  }

Comment: @TenaAndrade é um pouco difícil entender o código sem ver boa parte dele sabe... =/ Mas talvez para resolver esse problema, você pode trocar esse `for` por um `for` mais clássico. Assim: `for(var x=0;x<=newMessagesWin.length;x++) { newMessagesWin[x] = false }`.
É que eu não sei o que vem nessa variável **newMessagesWin** para poder te dizer algo melhor...

Comment: oie amor o código ta la no link que eu botei, mto obrigada ta dando certo, agora é esses, ta pedindo pra colocar em função, ja tentei de tudo: setTimeout('$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent").scrollTop($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);', 7000); // yet another strange ie bug

            }

            setTimeout('chatHeartbeat();',chatHeartbeatTime);